# Find $\sum _0^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^nn!}$

Tags: calculus

Find $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^nn!}$$

I know it's less than $$2 = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n}$$

Comment: $\sqrt{\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{k!}}} = \sqrt{e}$

Answer (score 15):

Hint: $$e^{x} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n}}{n!}$$